# Identifying duplicate rows among discrete sets of records in a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere, however I'm struggling to find the correct terminology…

Here is some data (Facebook audience sizes, as it happens) that I'm collecting at regular intervals.

Each test is a `target` and there are two `batches`, 18 and 19 (but there will be many more in the full dataset).

```
+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------------------+
| target | batch | location | daily | created_at          |
+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|  53003 |    18 | Austria  | 12117 | 2019-05-27 10:55:48 |
|  53003 |    19 | Austria  | 12663 | 2019-05-29 01:18:25 |
|  53004 |    18 | Austria  |  4999 | 2019-05-27 10:55:49 |
|  53004 |    19 | Austria  |  4999 | 2019-05-29 01:18:26 |
|  53005 |    18 | Austria  |   999 | 2019-05-27 10:55:50 |
|  53005 |    19 | Austria  |   997 | 2019-05-28 22:19:25 |
+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

I want to filter by days where `batch` 18 and 19 for the same `target` have the same `daily` value.

So I'd get something like the following (because target 53004 is the only one with the same result for both days).

Note: the important thing is I want each target to be compared first, in isolation, so if another target had daily=4999 for both batches, it would count separately, and if two targets by coincidence had, say, daily=123, but for one batch only each, they also wouldn't count as a match.

```
+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------------------+
| target | batch | location | daily | created_at          |
+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|  53004 |   n/a | Austria  |  4999 | n/a                 |
+--------+-------+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

(The *n/a* s are just to indicate those columns will no longer be single values and I don't care about them.)

Comment: @RaymondNijland where the value of `daily` is the same for each and every `batch` in the same `target`.

Comment: yes i removed mine comment, i noticed that also after mine comment when i reread the question once more..

Comment: but annyhow *"I want to filter by days where batch 18 and 19 for the same target have the same daily value."* and *"Note: the important thing is I want each target to be compared first, in isolation, so if another target had daily=4999 for both batches, it would count separately"* how does that look the example data and expected results does not include this.

Comment: Also can there be more then two records? If not then @stickybit 's answer looks like the solution to your question.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, there can be - "there are two batches, 18 and 19 (but there will be many more in the full dataset)" - min() and max() would still work for a larger group though presumably?

Comment: in this case it would as it seams you want to wanting to select the `MAX()` annyway i believe as your example data and expected results does not match up.. stickybit's answer is a smart way if faster checking if there are alteast two records within a group..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can aggreagte and check in a `HAVING` clause that the minimum and the maximum are equal.

```
SELECT target,
       'n/a' batch,
       location,
       max(daily) daily,
       'n/a' created_at
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY target,
                location
       HAVING min(daily) = max(daily);
```